# JavaScript - Updating variables to changing file content continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, loops

I am currently writing a program that reads a file input from the user, in which its contents will be changing in real time. My problem is that I can't seem to find a way to update the content continuously without having to refresh the page manually or re-upload the file. I am wondering if it is possible and if so, how I can do this.

What I attempted was to put a `setInterval` timer loop that will continuously call the `printFile` function, but it doesn't work.

```
var data;

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (isAPIAvailable()) {
            $('#files').bind('change', handleFileSelect);
    }
});


function isAPIAvailable() {
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        return true;
    } else {
       //...
        return false;
    }
}


function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        // read the file contents
        setInterval(printTable(file), 10000);
    }
}

function printTable(file, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        var csv = event.target.result;
        data = $.csv.toArrays(csv);
        console.log(data);
    };
    reader.onerror = function() {
        alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName);
    };
}
```

I just started working with JavaScript and Web Development, so I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: The way you've called `setInterval()` is wrong: what you're doing is calling `printTable(file)` *immediately* and then passing its return value (which is `undefined`) to `setInterval()`. You need to pass a reference to the function, so you could try `setInterval(printTable, 10000, file)`, or the equivalent `setInterval(function() { printTable(file); }, 10000)`.

Comment: I see, it works now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must pass function object to setInterval.
The way of setInterval call is wrong.

you could try following.

```
setInterval(printTable, 10000, file)
```

Following url is documentation about setInterval.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use jQuery to update your page content without refreshing the page.

```
$("#yourTable").empty()
$("#yourTable").append("<your new table></your new table>")
```